# Cost effective Self hosted Intranet Git server for 100+ users

Tags: git

As Bitbucket has turned down Server licenses and Gitlab has removed Starter edition, What are the Cost effective Onpremise Git server for 100+ users in Year 2021?

### Features required

- Branch Merge Restriction (e.g. Master branch merge is limited to certain users)
- Organization > repositories
- Role based security
- Pull Request & Code review comments
- Active directory authentication (Nice to have)
- Tagging releases

### Operating System

- Ubuntu or Cent OS

### Licensing

- Open source/Free
- Perpetual Commercial

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) If you're looking for software to self-host, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Without knowing what features you need (eg CI), it's hard to give good answers. Of course you could use GitLab CE and self-host it, as you mentioned it already.

Comment: @Izzy, Yes, I am looking for self-host

Comment: In that case someone just beat me to my suggestion (I'm using Gitea myself, and it's also used by Codeberg.org). Gogs is quite similar to it (but other than fruggiero suggests, neither is a Github clone, though the basic look is quite similar). As I already wrote, GitLab can be self-hosted as well (GitLab CE is an open-source Community Edition).

Comment: @lzzy, Gitlab CE lacks Required Approvals, we were thinking to use it to guard merges to Master branch https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html

Comment: Looks like your list of requirements isn't complete then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) (basically a clone of GitHub).

It should have all the features you are searching for:

- Integration with Active Directory through LDAP
- Organizations
- Pull requests with comments
- Release tagging
- User management

I'm not sure about the granularity of users & roles, but you can try it yourself on the demo hosted here:

https://try.gitea.io/